# Is there a way to disable forward evaluation while using VJP in JAX?

Tags: python, jax

I use VJP frequently in my project. It runs the function that is subject to Jacobian computation and returns a primals_out together with the callable vjp function.
For example, custom VJP definition in JAX documentation is given like this:

```
from jax import custom_vjp

@custom_vjp
def f(x, y):
  return jnp.sin(x) * y

def f_fwd(x, y):
# Returns primal output and residuals to be used in backward pass by f_bwd.
  return f(x, y), (jnp.cos(x), jnp.sin(x), y)

def f_bwd(res, g):
  cos_x, sin_x, y = res # Gets residuals computed in f_fwd
  return (cos_x * g * y, sin_x * g)

f.defvjp(f_fwd, f_bwd)
```

In this example, we see that evaluation of the forward function is required when using VJP. This is also the case when using regular VJP instead of a custom defined one. However, when the evaluation of function costs highly and since I have already run that function somewhere in my code, I don't want VJP to evaluate that function one more time.

So, is there any way to indicate that a function will not be evaluated when computing its VJP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to explicitly disable forward evaluation in this context, but if you wrap your computation in a `jit` compilation, the XLA compiler will automatically do dead code elimination and trim unused branches from the computation graph.